# Stacked horizontal divs along bottom is hiding scroll bars under container scroll bar

Tags: css, html

I wish to have an undetermined number of divs along the bottom, stacked horizontal. When there are too many to fit, they will be scrollable.

The div has a list inside it. When this list grows it will have a vertical scroll bar. The problem is that the bottom of that vertical scroll bar is under the parent horizontal scroll bar.  How can I make the whole scrollbar accessable the whole time the outer horizontal scroll bar is showing or not?

I am using chrome where the problem looks more severe than IE.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/valamas/G2wDc/)**

Here is my html where the class window is repeated

**Cut down html**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="window">
        <div class="heading">heading</div>
        <div class="list">
        listing<br>..... repeated ....
        </div>
    </div>
    ..... window class repeated ....
</div>
```

**css**

```
body
{
    overflow: scroll;
}
.outer
{
    position: fixed;
    height: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.window
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: White;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:normal;

}
.heading
{
    color: purple;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
.list
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: you mean to remove the horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: nope, that needs to stay. i need the vertical scroll bars to not appear under the horizontal bar.

Comment: why not remove the scrollbar and put a custom one there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome was doing something wacky with positioning. Padding-bottom: 20px seemed to fix it in Chrome without screwing over IE or Firefox. I did not test on Safari, but it should work there too.

```
body
{
    overflow: scroll;
}
.outer
{
    position: fixed;
    height: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.window
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: White;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:normal;

}

.heading
{
    color: purple;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}
.list
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It seems that the 20px padding is based on the height of the heading. My development heading was larger and so I needed to increase the padding size. I am considering using jquery to do this. Thanks for the clue.